# How to replace contents of div instead of append when php script is running through XMLHttprequest?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to make the div be replaced with the php echo value instead of being appended to the div as it does now with the following code?

PHP File (generator.php) :

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

function output($val)
{

echo $val.str_repeat(" ",5000);
sleep(2);

}

output('Begin... (counting to 10)');

for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    output($i+1);
}

output('End...');

?>
```

Calling HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function start() {

    try {
        xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = refreshwait;
    xmlhttp.open('GET', './generator.php', true);
    xmlhttp.send('null');
    refresher;
    }


function refresher(){

    window.setTimeout(refreshwait,1000)

}


function refreshwait() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){

            var code = 'Finished';
            document.getElementById('view_area').innerHTML = code;  
        }

    }else{

        var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        //document.getElementById("view_area").innerHTML = responseText;


        $("#view_area").html(responseText);


    }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="a_form">
<form id="aform">
<input name="Generate" onClick="start()" type="button" value="Generate Fresh File" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="view_area"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you have something like: <div id="1">one</div> and you are getting, from php, <div id="2">two</div> and you don't want it to be like this: <div id="1"><div id="2">two</div></div> you just want it to be <div id="2">two</div> ?  If that is the case then i think you could use [jquery .replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Comment: I want a number printed to the html, then it would be completely erased and then the next number would show in it's place etc etc The php file seems to be building a list in itself so when I call it using ajax it gives me everything it has done up to that point when all i want it to give is the last number it is up to. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Yes, it does, I misread the question.  I removed my answer, since it isn't valid.  The idea is that you want the php to loop and echo some string that javascript puts into the div.  I am not sure how to do this, outside of looping from the javascript side until php returns some value like "done".